# How to create a shifted border?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve something like this:
[image]

I tried to use the pseudo-element `:after` like this:

```
   .drink {
     background-color: $drink-bg;
     max-width: 50%;
     position: relative;

     &:after {
       position: absolute;
       top: -10px;
       left: 10px;
       right: 10px;
       bottom: 10px;
       border: 1px solid black;
     }

     img {
       max-width: 100%;
     }
   }
```

It doesn't seem to work. Do I have to use 2 elements to achieve this? Or I can use just 1 element?

Because the image is responsive, the border should "follow" the width and height of the image element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pseudo-element is actually styled correctly, and you are one small step away to get it to work: **you just need to declare `content: ''` on it**. Without a defined `content` property, the pseudo-element will not be rendered. This is because:

> On elements, [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/content) always computes to normal. On `::before` and `::after`, if normal is specified, computes to none.

By extension of logic, an element without any content will not be rendered.

```css
.drink {
  background-color: $drink-bg;
  max-width: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.drink:after {
  content: '';  /* Added this rule */
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.drink img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="drink">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x500" />
</div>
```